# glBlitFramebuffer does not copy all textures

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, frame-buffer

#### The setup

I have a working bloom shader implemented which creates a fbo with two textures attached to it.

1. The first texture holds the entire scene
2. The other only displays objects which are supposed to be bloomed in a postprocessing (ping pong) step

At the and the end both textures are added.

Here is the code which creates the according fbo:

```cpp
    void CreateHdrBloomFBO(GLuint &hdr_fbo, GLuint *color_buffers, GLuint *pingpong_fbo, GLuint *pingpong_color_buffers, GLuint &rbo_depth, float width, float height)
    {
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &hdr_fbo);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdr_fbo);
        glGenTextures(2, color_buffers);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_buffers[i]);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_buffers[i], 0);
        }

        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo_depth);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth);
        GLuint attachments[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
        glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);

        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            std::cout << "CORE::CREATE_FRAMEBUFFER_FAIL - Failed creating HDR/BLOOM buffers." << std::endl;
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glGenFramebuffers(2, pingpong_fbo);
        glGenTextures(2, pingpong_color_buffers);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpong_fbo[i]);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpong_color_buffers[i]);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpong_color_buffers[i], 0);

            if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
                std::cout << "CORE::CREATE_FRAMEBUFFER_FAIL - Failed creating HDR/BLOOM-pingpong buffers." << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

So my renderloop looks something like this.

```cpp
// 1. Bind fbo
// 2. Render scene 
// 3. Blur cube and earth fragments with two-pass Gaussian Blur
bool horizontal = true, first_iteration = true;
unsigned int amount = 10;
blur_shader.use();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingpong_fbo[horizontal]);
    blur_shader.set_int("horizontal", horizontal);
    // Note on the first iteration I take the second texture from above, which holds the objects which are supposed to get bloomed.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, first_iteration ? color_buffers[1] : pingpong_color_buffers[!horizontal]);
    core::RenderQuad(&quad_geometry);
    horizontal = !horizontal;
    if (first_iteration)
        first_iteration = false;
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// 4. Combine normal and bloom textures
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
bloom_final_shader.use();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_buffers[0]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingpong_color_buffers[!horizontal]);
bloom_final_shader.set_int("bloom", use_bloom);
bloom_final_shader.set_float("exposure", exposure);
core::RenderQuad(&quad_geometry);
```

This is what the output of the scene render looks like. The are the scene and the blooming targets:

[image]

In the first blooming step the correct image is passed and "ping ponged" afterwards.

[image]

The final image:

[image]

#### The problem

I want to implement antialiasing on top of the given process. Therfore I create a multisample fbo which also holds two textures:

```cpp
void CreateMsaaFBO(GLuint &target_fbo, GLuint *target_fbo_textures, GLuint &rbo_depth_stencil, float width, float height)
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &target_fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, target_fbo);
    glGenTextures(2, target_fbo_textures);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, target_fbo_textures[i]);
        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGB, width, height, GL_TRUE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,target_fbo_textures[i], 0);
    }
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo_depth_stencil);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth_stencil);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER,rbo_depth_stencil);
    GLuint attachments[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "CORE::CREATE_FRAMEBUFFER_FAIL - Failed creating MSAA buffer." << std::endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, 0);
}
```

So my Plan is to draw the scene as above this time using my msaa_fbo and use `glBlitFramebuffer` to copy antialiased textures to my original fbo:

```cpp
// 1. Bind msaa_fbo
// 2. Render scene 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, msaa_fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, hdr_fbo);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height, 0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
// 3. blur bright fragments with two-pass Gaussian Blur as above
// ...
```

It seems that only the first texture gets copied to the `hdr_fbo` and therfore the entire image is bloomed.

The output of the `msaa_fbo` looks correct:

[image]

This is the `glBindFramebuffer` in renderdoc which seems to target only one texture (the scene):

[image]

That is why the input of the pingpong loop is the entire scene:

[image]

As far as I get it should copy both textures (scene + bloom) to my target `hdr_fbo` buffer. Why doesn't it? I started learning those concept, so I am not ruling out that I am missing something fundamental.

Also note that a lot of the code is taken from [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the use of `glBlitFrameBuffer`. When using this to blit Color Buffers, according to the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting),

> One thing to keep in mind is this: when using GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT​,
> the only colors read will come from the *read color buffer* in the read
> FBO, *specified by glReadBuffer*. The colors written will only go to the
> draw color buffers in the write FBO, specified by glDrawBuffers. If
> multiple draw buffers are specified, then multiple color buffers are
> updated with the same data.

So simply speaking, when blitting color buffers, you need to specify what `ReadBuffer` by using [glReadBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Read_color_buffer) which takes in color attachment number when dealing with FBOs.

So in short, you can't expect to copy both the attachments or textures with a single blit call.

Also, can't you just render the anti-aliased scene once, blit this single texture to get a working copy of it usable in shaders and then extract the second texture which is essentially just the environment subtracted from it?